# What is the easiest way to extract array's values from another array's keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$array2 = [0,1,2,3];
```

I want to assign the values from the first array to another array according to the values from the second array as keys. So instead of doing it one by one like this:

```
$array3 = [$array1[$array2[0]],$array1[$array2[1]],$array1[$array2[2]],$array1[$array2[3]]];
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
$array3 = [$array1[$array2]];
```

But I got the following error:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type
```

What I want to get is:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3  [3] => 4 )
```

Any ideas what is the right way to do it?

Comment: `[$array1[$array2]` is missing a `]`.  Can you show what output you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably numerous ways to solve this.
Probably the simplest is to loop over the second array and add the corresponding values from the first into the new array...

```
$array3 = [];
foreach ( $array2 as $extract ) {
    $array3[] = $array1 [ $extract ];
}
print_r($array3);
```

Comment: Ops, It doesn't work actually. if you try to change the values from the second array then you get a different result.

Comment: Let's say that the second array is only one value: $array2 = [4]. If we apply your method we get Array ( [4] => 5 ). What I want to get is Array ( [0] => 5 )

Comment: I've updated the last code to add `array_values()`.

Comment: That's fixes the keys problem indeed. But there is another problem with the order. Let's say that $array2 = [1,0], the result will be Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ), what it should be is Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 )

Comment: It would be easier to use the first method (I will remove the second method as it would mean adding a sort as well).

Comment: I found an answer if you want to check it, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I found a short way:

```
array_map(function($x) use ($array1) { return $array1[$x]; }, $array2);
```

Comment: Your initial question didn't even have a solution with foreach, and then you advanced it to shorter way demand. Now, you posted a solution with array_map. Hard to believe you couldn't start with foreach loop but landed up correctly with shorter ways which are little trickier to script.

Answer (score 0):

A simple foreach loop should do the trick. Loop over second array and check if its key is set in the first array. If so, add to result, else skip.

```
$array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
$array2 = [0, 1, 2, 3];

$result = [];

foreach ($array2 as $value) {
    if (isset($array1[$value])) {
        $result[] = $array1[$value];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

From PHP7.4 you can use arrow function syntax and avoid the `use()` declaration.  If you don't want to call any custom functions and don't want a classic loop, you can make 3 native function calls to generate an indexed array of results.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9qhPk))

```
$array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
$array2 = [3, 4];

var_export(
    array_values(array_intersect_key($array1, array_flip($array2)))
);
// array ( 0 => 4, 1 => 5, )

var_export(
    array_map(fn($v) => $array1[$v], $array2)
);
// array ( 0 => 4, 1 => 5, )
```